# How Do I Load FastAI's exported pkl file?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pickle, fast-ai

I have trained my resnet model using the Google Colab's free GPU since my laptop does not have a GPU.
You can find that here - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FjwI26-fv1h3w5hlg-M5Fl_2nvWBvFzq?usp=sharing

Now, it's time to finally make predictions using the model which I have created. But the main problem which I am facing is the loading of the model. Of course, I will load the `pkl` or `pth` file onto my local environment and call the `predict()` method on it but apparently, in order to load the model, you need the object of the `Learner` class itself.

In my case, it should be the object of the `cnn_learner` class. In order to make the object of that class, I will need to define everything - the `ImageDataLoaders` and load the images too and only then, i'll be able to make the object of `cnn_learner` class by going `model = cnn_learner(dls, resnet18, metrics=error_rate` where `dls` would be the object of `ImageDataLoaders`

How do I work around this? Because honestly this seems a little bit counter-intuitive to me. Even the fastai documentation suggests that I will need all the code when I was exporting my model in order to load the model. But the main point of exporting the fully trained model is to use it on any environment I wish to just because it is fully trained and I can just call the `predict()` method on it and get my predictions!

Also, I have saved the model in both the `pkl` format by using `model.export` and `pth` format by using `model.save`

If someone could help me in this, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Tried everything.
Browsed the documentation and also experimented with the documentation code on my own but it was no luck.

Comment: What have you tried? We can't exactly provide meaningful suggestions if we don't know what you tried and how it failed. Also, instead of just providing a link to the colab, include a snippet of the relevant sections such as where you convert it to a `pkl` or `pth` and where you tried to load from the `pkl` or `pth` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `export` method of learner as follows

```
learn.export("/content/model.pkl")
```

To load the model again, use `load_learner`

```
load_learner('/content/model.pkl')
```

https://docs.fast.ai/learner.html